# Sistema de Avaliação de Usuários com notas unicas

Tags: php, html

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de avaliação dos funcionários da minha equipe. No caso, esse sistema seria feito da seguinte maneira. 
Um usuário que irá avaliar poderá fazer 5 avaliações somente. 
Essas 5 avaliações poderão serão com notas de 1 a 5 sendo que essas notas não poderão se repetir. Ou seja o Usuário avaliador dará a nota de 5 para um outro colaborador, mas ele não poderá repetir a nota 5 para outro colaborador.

No caso, usei esse teste em SQL para retornar as notas que já foram dadas.

```
SELECT [nota] FROM [dbo].[tb_result_destaque] WHERE [usr_reg] = 
'usuario'
```

No caso, joguei essa consulta para dentro do PHP e fiz um teste para ler todas as notas que já foram atribuidas e tentei jogar ela dentro de um array e usando explode para fazer a comparação. Ae caso a nota já tenha sido dada, ele iria deixar um disable na opção do select HTML.

```
<option disabled value="1">1</option>
```

Porém nem nessa parte está chegando, já que com o teste, ele lê todas as notas porém eu não consigo passar todas as notas para fora do While
Segue abaixo um trecho do código que estou tentando elaborar

```
 $result = $sql->execute($consultaNota); 
   while(!$result->EOF) { 
       $nota = $result->Fields['nota']->Value;
         $notaArray = array($nota); 

         $result->MoveNext(); 
   }
```

NO caso cheguei a colocar um explode e um foreach entre o array e o movenext e tentei passar os dados para fora, mas como disse nenhum funcionou. Eu populei o banco e no caso o usuário já tinha dado as notas 1,4 e 5 quando preciso passar para fora do Loop ele só mostra o 1.

No caso o que preciso fazer?